# What do triple brackets (i.e. {{{ stuff }}}) mean in Javascript/Typescript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm going through the code on a new project I'd like to contribute to, and the author has defined lots of methods using triple brackets, like this:

```
deinitialize() {{{
    this.destroyed = true;
    $(window).off("resize", this.resize as () => void);
    if (this.resize_debounce) {
        clearTimeout(this.resize_debounce);
        this.resize_debounce = null;
    }
    this.svg.remove();
    this.container = null;
}}}
```

I've never seen a triple bracket (brace? mustache?) used in that manner. My only experience with them has been in data binding with something like Polymer. What's going on here?

The project is written in typescript (which I also have no experience with), and this specific bit is in a .tsx file. It also uses React, which is probably irrelevant. Does this functionality come from one of those, or is it native JS that I've never seen?

The source code is here: https://github.com/online-go/online-go.com/blob/devel/src/components/RatingsChart/RatingsChart.tsx

Also, I apologize if this isn't clearly worded. I'm not really sure where these are coming from, and I'm not really familiar with the language or FWs used in this project. Thanks for your patience! (And editing, if required :))

Comment: AFAICT, it does absolutely nothing. You can use as many pairs of braces as you like.

Comment: It's nothing, just extra braces.  Try this in your browsers console window:  `function foo() {{{ console.log(1); }}};  foo()`.  It's just extra braces.  As long as the braces match, you can use 20 braces if you really wanted.  It wouldn't affect anything.

Comment: It's definitely unusual however.

Comment: It is unusual, the only person who knows why is the author. Maybe its a convention they use for react component built in methods

Comment: Extra Blocks FTW!

Comment: It's entirely possible that it's part of some templating engine, but if so, it's non-standard and we wouldn't know anything about it.  The only way to know for sure would be to remove the extra braces and see if it affects your software's behavior.

Comment: Just to be sure, Ive asked my friendly neighbourhood react devs :)

Comment: you can put extra blocks about anywhere, not just around functions. you can even label the blocks..

Comment: @Jamiec `AFAICT, it does absolutely nothing` It might generate more block level scopes, so it might waste CPU resources.. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In javascript statements you can use as many *pairs* of matching braces as you like:

```js
function test(){{{
   console.log("Im in lots of braces.");
}}}

test();
```

There is no change in behaviour whatsoever*. There is also nothing special in react that has any affect using this code.

My best guess is that the developer of the linked code follows some sort of convention for react components. But as far as I can tell it is not one used by the wider community, otherwise we would see this a lot more.

<sub>* Except perhaps a few extra nanoseconds to process it. H/T:Keith ;)</sub>

Comment: I also noticed that none of the functions/methods are declared with "function" or something like `class.prototype.method = blah(){{{}}}`. Is that a general typescript thing, or something else non-standard? Everything follows ES6 standards, or the typescript equivalent, as far as I can tell.

Comment: @ckersch that's just because they're class functions which dont use the keyword `function`

Comment: `few extra nanoseconds`, interestingly, doing a quick performance test in Chrome,.   doing an extra `{{` is about 3 times slower, but what is strange doing ten of them it doesn't get any slower. In fact 10 seems a tad faster than 2,.  But of course the winner is 1.

Comment: Actually scrap that, it's even stranger.. :)  changing the order, whatever comes first is the fastest.  So that would seem like Chrome TurboFan is slowing things down maybe,.

Comment: It is almost certain that the original developer was using vim with folding.  See below.

Answer (score 2):

simply, its because if there were another pair of brackets in an [object](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp) inside the function, it would be hard to read.

example (they get way harder to read than this):

```
function translate(num){
    var translations = {
         1: 'one',
         2: 'two',
         3: 'three',
         4: 'four',
         5: 'five',
         6: 'six'
    };


    return translations[num];
};
```

it just makes it easier (especially when theres more than one prototype or object. the multibrackets make that easier. you can use }, }}, }}}, }}}}, }}}}}, ... to make it easier to read, like this:

```
function translate(num){{
    var translations = {
         1: 'one',
         2: 'two',
         3: 'three',
         4: 'four',
         5: 'five',
         6: 'six'
    };
 }};
```

you can only do it to the function, not the object. this also works with brackets; you can use ', ", "', "", ""', """, ... and anything after that!
the multi-parenthesis are to be able to put other parenthesis inside it without closing it:

```
 var question = "' "how'd you do that?" said Tom "';
 // triple brackets
```

in that example, theyre used to allow the single parenthesis as an apostrophe, and the double parenthesis as speech parenthesis.

happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

I frequently use this {{{ }}} way of segmenting my code, and also for structuring any text file.
It is a widely-accepted convention for folding, and it is the default foldmarker for the `vim` editor.

See the `/usr/share/vim/vim82/doc/usr_28.txt` file in your GNU/Linux distribution (with `vim` installed, of course).

In a nutshell, folding is a method to "fold" and "unfold" parts of a file.  It can be done by using indentation levels (`:set foldmethod=indent`) or by using specific markers (`set foldmethod=marker`).  The default markers are these triple parentheses `{{{,}}}`.  Custom markers can be manually specified like this: `:set foldmarker={,}` (this is useful for C code, for instance).

Check this documentation:
https://www.vimfromscratch.com/articles/vim-folding

Also check the answers here:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/141097/how-to-enable-and-use-code-folding-in-vim

Note that, when using specific foldmarkers, it is often advisable to include these markers in comments.

For instance, this is a "vim-foldable" python code:

```py
class Toutou: # {{{

    def __init__(self, name, age): # {{{
        self.name = name  # Public attribute
        self._age = age   # Non-Public attribute
    # }}}

    def bark(self):
        print("waf, waf.")

    def (pat):
        print("swinging my tail with joy and happiness")

# }}}
```

It may look ugly here; but when editing it with vim, it allows to see the class within one fold, and only the two methods unfold, without seeing the constructor.  This can be adapted as anyone likes.

In Javascript, there is apparently no need to comment out those foldmarkers.